# Does PHP's session_unset kill the entire session including the session Id?

Tags: php, session

When using PHP's `session_unset()` without specifying a session variable to unset, does it destroy all the current session variables including the session id, or does it keep the session id and destroy only the variables.

Also, is it necessary to destroy each session variable using `session_unset()` or will `session_unset()` destroy all of them?

What I'd like to do is, when a user logs out, I'd like to keep the session alive, but destroy all his set session variables. Eg: sesUserId, sesUserName etc.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the session alive?

Comment: i think you need to learn more about sessions in php

Comment: So I know if he logged in using another account. I'll be able to tell using the session Id :-) That's my thinking.

Comment: @Ajaxkevi What you say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session_unset()` frees all session variables / empties the array but keeps the session alive.

`session_destroy()` destroys the session completely (and removes session file from server).

`unset($_SESSION['example'])` frees an individual session variable.

It is worth noting that when using `session_destroy` the session variables will still be in the array on that one page load.